# Folder structure and SSR fetching in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have the following folder structure in my Next.js app.

```
- pages/
  - admin/
    - admin.js
  - users/
    - users.js
```

But I am unable to fetch data with SSR. For Example I was trying to fetch user data inside users directory as follows but I got undefined response.

Here is the api call with SSR.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function User({ user }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <p>{user.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const res = await fetch(`https://api.example.com/users/${id}`);
  const user = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      user,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to acces this User page? I mean what's the URL for it?